# How to count the number of bits in the digits in python

Tags: python, bit

I am trying to count the number of bits in the given number using python:

```
def countBit(self, n: int) -> int:
    l=[int(d) for d in str(n)]
    return(sum(l))
```

The input given to this function is 00000000000000000000000000001011 and the output expected is 3 but I am getting 2 as the output.

Can you suggest me a way to proceed ?

Comment: "The input given to this function is 00000000000000000000000000001011" What does this mean? That is not valid Python syntax for an integer. Please keep in mind that numbers **do not have digits**, or bits, or anything else. Those are all things that are *used to represent* a numeric value.

Comment: You cannot "count the bits" in an integer (even though you can write it as `1011` in binary), just like you cannot "count the digits" in that same integer (even though you can write it as `11` in decimal), just like you cannot "count the letters" in that same integer (even though you can write it as `eleven` in English). You can count bits *in a binary representation*, digits *in a decimal representation*, and letters *in a textual representation*.

Comment: The binary number `1011` is equivalent to decimal `11`. When you add the digits of that, you get `2`.

Comment: That said: if you expected `00000000000000000000000000001011` to be a binary representation (for example, you use something like `int('00000000000000000000000000001011', 2)` to convert a string to integer), then of course the *decimal* representation (which is what you get from `str` without specifying a base) will have two digits, because the numeric value is eleven (written `11` in decimal, so that the string is `'11'`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're adding the digits in the decimal representation of the number, not the binary representation.

From your expected output, I guess you actually want to only count the `1` bits, not the `0` bits.

Use the `bin()` function to convert the number to a binary string.

```
def countBit(n: int) -> int:
    return sum(b == '1' for b in bin(n))
```

Answer (score 0):

In python 3.10+ there is a bit_count function.

I use this to count all (1) bits in a file:

```
bcount=sum([x.bit_count() for x in open("file.bin","rb").read()])
```

To count bits in a single byte:

```
>>> x=0x55
>>> x.bit_count()
4
```